# Setting $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT on fish shell from bash shell equivalence

Tags: linux, bash, fish

I'm trying to set $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT for fish shell in config.fish, I previously had the configuration set on my previous linux installation which used bash as follows:

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Library/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools
```

But now I want to set it for my new Garuda Linux installation which uses Fish shell. The above configuration does not work. I tried the following configuration and I'm not sure if it's correct:

```
set -x ANDROID_SDK_ROOT $home/Android/Sdk
set -x PATH $PATH $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator
set -x PATH $PATH $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't want to `set PATH $PATH /some/dir` -- that will add /some/dir again, regardless if it's already in there.

Also, `$HOME/Library/Android/Sdk` not `$home/Android/Sdk` -- this is probably the source of "does not work".

You want

```
set -x ANDROID_SDK_ROOT $HOME/Library/Android/Sdk
fish_add_path  $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator  $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools
```

https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/fish_add_path.html?highlight=add

Comment: It worked perfectly. But for my instance the Android folder is created in the $HOME directory hence the missing Library folder on my path.